# I'm having trouble making an armor creation script in unity for gaming

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inheritance

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public enum EquipmentType
{
    Helmet,
    Chest,
    Gloves,
    Boots,
    Weapon1,
    Weapon2,
    Accessory1,
    Accessory2,
    Shoulder,
    Belt,
    Trinket1,
    Trinket2,
}

namespace Armor
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public class ArmorSystem : MonoBehaviour 
    {
        [Header("Stats")]
        public int strength;
        public int intellect;
        public int vitality;
        public int agility;
        Item item;

        [Header("Damage")]
        public float fireDamage;
        public float frostDamage;
        public float shadowDamage;
        public string itemName;

        [Header("ItemStats")]
        public float curDurability;
        public float maxDurability;
        public float durabilityDecay;
        public float moveSpeedDecay;
        public float movespeed;
        public float decay;
        public float movsped;
        [SerializeField]
        EquipmentType EquipmentType;

        [Header("Resistance")]
        public float fireResistance;
        public float frostResistance;
        public float shadowResistance;

        [Header("DamageReduction")]
        public float resistance;
        public float damage;
        public float damageReduction;
        public float armor;
        public int ItemLevel;
        public int ItemRarity;

        [Header("Currency")]
        public float money;
        public float repairCost;


        [Header("Bools")]
        bool moveDecay;
        public bool inDestructible;
        public string ItemQualityname;

        public float RepairCost
        {
            get { return repairCost; }
            set { repairCost = value; }
        }

        public float Decay
        {
            get { return decay; }
            set { decay = value; }
        }

        public void Awake()
        {
            ChooseItemType();
            inDestructible = (Random.value < 0.1);
            ItemRarity = Random.Range(0, 4);
            ItemLevel = Random.Range(0, 300);
            ArmorQuality();
            SetDurability();
            Decay = maxDurability / 10000;
            curDurability -= Decay;
            curDurability -= moveSpeedDecay;
            repairCost = curDurability - maxDurability;
            ItemLevelStats();
            money = 4000;

    }

         public void inDestructibled()
        {
            moveSpeedDecay = 0;
            decay = 0;
        }

        void ArmorQuality()
        {
            if(ItemRarity == 0)
            {
                ItemQualityname = "Trash";
            }
            if(ItemRarity == 1)
            {
                ItemQualityname = "Epic";
            }
            if (ItemRarity == 2)
            {
                ItemQualityname = "Rare";
            }
            if (ItemRarity == 3)
            {
                ItemQualityname = "Uncommon";
            }
            if (ItemRarity == 4)
            {
                ItemQualityname = "Common";
            }
        }

        public void ChooseItemType()
        {
            int randomTemp = Random.Range(1, 4);
            if(randomTemp == 1)
            {
                EquipmentType = EquipmentType.Helmet;
            }
            if (randomTemp == 2)
            {
                EquipmentType = EquipmentType.Chest;
            }
            if (randomTemp == 3)
            {
                EquipmentType = EquipmentType.Gloves;
            }
            if (randomTemp == 4)
            {
                EquipmentType = EquipmentType.Boots;
            }
        }

        public void CreateArmor()
        {

        }

        public void SetDurability()
        {
            maxDurability = 100;
            curDurability = 100;
        }

        public void Reduction()
        {
            damageReduction = armor - damage;       
        }

        public void Update()
        {
            Repair();

            repairCost = repairCost + decay;

            if (inDestructible == true)
            {
                inDestructibled();

            }
            if(inDestructible == false)
            {
                ArmorDecay();
            }

        }

        public void ArmorDecay()
        {
            decay = maxDurability / 10000;
            curDurability -= decay;
            curDurability -= moveSpeedDecay;

            if (movespeed > 0)
            {
                moveDecay = true;
                moveSpeedDecay = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                moveDecay = false;
                moveSpeedDecay = 0;
            }
        }

        public void ItemLevelStats()
        {
            strength = 1;
            intellect = 1;
            vitality = 1;
            agility = 1;
            strength = (ItemLevel * strength) / 5;
            agility = (ItemLevel * agility) / 5;
            intellect = (ItemLevel * intellect) / 5;
            vitality = (ItemLevel * vitality) / 5;
        }

        public void ClassStatBonus()
        {

        }

        public void Resistance()
        {
            fireResistance -= fireDamage;
            frostResistance -= frostDamage;
            shadowResistance -= shadowDamage;
        }

        public void Broken()
        {
            if (curDurability <= 0)
            {
                Debug.Log(itemName + " is broken!");

            }
        }

        public void Repair()
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
            {
                curDurability = maxDurability;
                money -= repairCost;
                repairCost = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I make another script inherit the varibles in the current script. I can't attach scripts not inherited by monoBehaviour to GameObject like weapons...

Comment: If `a` inherits `b`, and `b` inherits `MonoBehaviour`, it's also true that `a` inherits `MonoBehaviour`. Solution: make `b` inherit `MonoBehaviour`. (i.e. a -> b -> MonoBehaviour)

Comment: Also, format your post. Ctrl-K intents code blocks.

Comment: If you are speaking about variables like `Item`, `EquipmentType` and `moveDecay` they are implicitely `private` by default if not explicitly defined otherwise. Make them at least `protected` or `public` otherwise you have no access in the inherited class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a script inherit **ArmorSystem** normal, it will inherit **Monobehavior** already. Better write all function in **ArmorSystem** to virtual.

eg:

```
namespace Armor
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public class HeavyAmor : ArmorSystem 
{
}
```

Comment: They don't *all* need to be `virtual` .. just the ones you want to be able to override/extend later

Comment: Yep, but better use virtual bro, it make you easy customize your code.

Comment: I just would not recommend to generalize this ... it's the same like making everything public. It's not very clean